# Flutter: Display two FutureBuilders data one after another in a single page

Tags: flutter

I have two FutureBuilder data to be displayed in a single page one after another i.e. I want to append second FutureBuilder data to first one. When I use the following code, it divides the screen into two fixed parts the upper half displays the first FutureBuilder data and the lower half displays the second FutureBuilder data and both are scrollable separately. If I use body:SingleChildScrollView instead body:SafeArea the resulting output is a white screen (no data on screen) with error in console

> Failed assertion: line 2009 pos 12: 'hasSize' The relevant error-causing widget was Scaffold

Here is the complete program:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class GetUserData extends StatefulWidget {
  const GetUserData({super.key});

  @override
  State<GetUserData> createState() => _GetUserDataState();
}

class _GetUserDataState extends State<GetUserData> {
  Future<List> getUserData() async {
    String url = 'https://telugu-signaler.000webhostapp.com/get_user.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: '');
    var allUserData = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
    return allUserData;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Get User Data'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true, //add this line
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 1,
                          mainAxisExtent: 150.0,
                        ),

                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          String userFirstName =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_first_name'];
                          String userLastName =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_last_name'];

                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                child: Text(
                                  'First Name: $userFirstName',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightBlue,
                                child: Text(
                                  'Last Name: $userLastName',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 8,
              child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: getUserData(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true, //add this line
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                          mainAxisExtent: 150.0,
                        ),

                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          String userDistrict =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_district'];
                          String userState =
                              snapshot.data![index]['user_state'];

                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  'District: $userDistrict',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                color: Colors.lightGreen,
                                child: Text(
                                  'State: $userState',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: use `NestedScrollView` or `CustomScrollView` with slivers.

Comment: someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expanded 2 widgets in column with same flex. So it's normal to split screen. You have to remove Expanded widgets. Then disable scrolling on GridViews by adding `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to GridView. Then change the SafeArea with SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad to hear that it is working fine.